# Stuck on showing an elementary inequality

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following problem:

Let $X = \{a+bx : a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Define $d(f,g) = sup_{0 \le x \le 1} |f(x) - g(x)|$ for $f,g \in X$.

$i)$ Show that d is a distance.

$ ii)$ For $f = a + bx$ and $g = c + dx$, show that $|a-c| \le d(f,g)$ and $|b-d| \le 2d(f,g).$

$iii)$ Show that X equipped with $d$ is complete.

I've shown $i$, but I am unable to prove $ii$. Can anyone offer a hint as to where to begin? I've tried splitting the absolute value up using the triangle inequality, but then you have to handle so many cases that I felt I was doing something wrong.

edit: Using the reverse triangle inequality, I have that $|a-c| \le sup_{0 \le x \le 1}||a-c|-|x(b-d)|| \le sup_{0 \le x \le 1}|a-c + x(b-d)| = d(f,g)$. I am still unable to do the second part of $ii$.

Comment: I may have just shown $|a-c| \le d(f,g)$ using the reverse triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1):

if $x=0$, $|f(x)-g(x)|=|a-c|\leq d(f,g)$.

$ |f(-1)-g(-1)|=|a-c-(b-d)|\leq d(f,g)$, we deduce that $||b-d|-|a-c||\leq d(f,g)$, we deduce that $|b-d|-|a-c|\leq d(f,g)$ and $|b-d|\leq |a-c|+d(f,g)\leq 2d(f,g)$.

Comment: Thank you, I believe I solved this one using the reverse triangle inequality. I'm still unsure of the second part of the problem though.

Comment: Oh okay, I see. Thank you for all of your help!